# Not display if the input is not empty

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am displaying an error message if the user doesn't enters a username but when the user enters a username it shows `"username": null`. How i can not show any errors when there are none I tried to add if statement inside array it will not work

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if(empty($username)){
    $username_error = "Please enter a Username";
}
  $json = array(
        'ErrorMsg' => array( 

         'username' => $username_error,
        ),
        'booleanFlag' => TRUE,    
    );
```

Comment: I usually clear all the errors on the form submit

Comment: Check your if statement, there is spelling mistake
Make correct as
if(empty($username)){

Comment: @MaxZoom if there is a value in username i dont want to show the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give an alternate value (blank) for your $username_error:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
if(empty($username)){
    $username_error = "Please enter a Username";
} else {
    $username_error = "";
}
$json = array(
    'ErrorMsg' => array( 
       'username' => $username_error,
     ),
    'booleanFlag' => TRUE,    
);
```